# Display Pandas output in html page

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django as a web-framework, I have been trying to display data from csv file onto HTML page with pandas, I tried to find any available project online but I couldn't.

I have an index.html file /appl/templates/appl/index.html

I don't have exact idea of how exactly I should display the data from Python code, I tried to put all python code inside {{...}} in HTML but it gave me errors, inside /appl/data.py file I am trying to read data with pandas code
....

```
file_data=pd.read_csv('F:\lending-club-data.csv')
```

....

I want to somehow put the output of 'file_data' inside HTML file and display but I am unable to do it.
A basic small snippet of work_around code for the above problem is needed.

Comment: You should read and follow [the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/tutorial01/) and then come back to this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply i did went through that poll administration application and i could successfully run it but here i am trying to put the output of pandas dataframe output onto html file, and i am unable to get any idea of how it can done.

Comment: Did you follow all 5 steps and read thoroughly?

Comment: Did you try doing `file_data.to_html('file_name.html')`?

Comment: Yes i followed all 5 steps, btw  i didn't try file_data.to_html('file_name.html') how and where should i put that piece of code into my /template/index.html page. is it simply putting that code snippet inside index.html will do the work?